# What are the factors affecting the amount of blood refractive index?

Tags: optics, refraction, biology

I read an article normal blood refractive index is 1.35. So it's for everybody?
I want simulate a sensor to detection flu virus using micro ring resonator then I find the wavelength shift 24 nm but my university professor asked me maybe it's different? Please help me.

Comment: it would be helpful to reference the article and quote the wavelength of the em radiation

Answer (score 1):

According to [J. of Biomedical Optics, 24(3), 035003 (2019)](https://www.spiedigitallibrary.org/journals/journal-of-biomedical-optics/volume-24/issue-03/035003/Measurement-of-the-refractive-index-of-whole-blood-and-its/10.1117/1.JBO.24.3.035003.full?SSO=1),

> the [refractive index] values of whole blood are reported from 1.36 to 1.44

Comment: thank you so much